# is there an option in unity to hide objects, UI elements, 3d model?

Tags: unity-game-engine, hide, augmented-reality, vuforia

I'm new to unity and i'm trying to make an AR app, animal card game.
I have one scene/one AR camera (i'm not sure if it would be better to have one scene per animal) , I have one UI button that pop up when an image target is detected and I want to make more, one for each animal but my problem is that I can only put the buttons in one place in the canvas.
I would like to know if there is somewhere an option to make my object invisible just in the editor ?
thank you.

Answer (score 3):

There's two ways in which you can hide objects in the editor - its either using [Layers](https://unity3d.com/learn/tutorials/topics/interface-essentials/layers) (you can set layer visibility in the editor and distribute objects among layers.

The alternative is to use gameobject's HideFlags but its realtively more complex (and easy to lost objects in the scene).

If you want to hide objects in the gameplay, theres two ways - you either disable the whole gameobject (using [`gameObject.SetActive`](https://unity3d.com/learn/tutorials/topics/scripting/activating-gameobjects)), or you disable its rendering component (using [`GetComponent` + `enabled` variable](https://unity3d.com/learn/tutorials/topics/scripting/enabling-and-disabling-components). Third way exists for UI objects - that's using [CanvasGroup component](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/class-CanvasGroup.html)

Comment: thanks you for your answer, I will  try and see what fits  best for my problem